# How to filter on a column and then retrieve a few columns in pandas dataframe in one command?

Tags: python, pandas

To filter a dataframe:

```
df_filtered = df[df["A"] > 0].copy()

Output:

                   A         B         C         D
2013-01-01  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059 -1.135632
2013-01-02  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
2013-01-04  0.721555 -0.706771 -1.039575  0.271860
```

To select only columns C and D from filtered result:

```
df_result = df_filtered [['C', 'D']].copy()

 Output:
    
    C         D
   -1.509059 -1.135632
    0.119209 -1.044236
   -1.039575  0.271860
```

Is there any way to perform the filter and select the 2 columns in one command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `list`:

```
df_result = df.loc[df["A"] > 0, ['C', 'D']].copy()
print (df_result)
                   C         D
2013-01-01 -1.509059 -1.135632
2013-01-02  0.119209 -1.044236
2013-01-04 -1.039575  0.271860
```

If need default `RangeIndex`:

```
df_result = df.loc[df["A"] > 0, ['C', 'D']].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Does `df[df["A"] > 0]` get internally executed as `df.loc[df["A"] > 0]` ?

Comment: @variable - I think not, first is pure [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)-, for second is combination [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and `DataFrame.loc`.